# Как восстановить удаленные разделы жесткого диска с LVM-шифрованием?

Tags: hdd, восстановление

Спутал винчестеры, и удалил все разделы жесткого диска. Больше никаких операций записи на этом винчестере не производилось. Стояла ubuntu с lvm-шифрованием. На жестком диске крайне важные данные заказчика, и несколько месяцев ежедневной(и даже еженочной работы) Нужно любой ценой восстановить разделы. Как это сделать?

P.S. Пока что запустил gparted на поиск удаленных разделов, сканировать будет в районе 30 часов.

Comment: точные размеры разделов, я так понимаю, не помнишь? и после записи перезагружался? диск не отмонтировался?

Comment: Перезагружался. Ошибочное удаление произошло этим долбаным виндовым установщиком, когда хотел переустановить ось на другом венике, но подтер не тот. Удалил только разделы и все. Там на все 750 гб был один раздел, завернутый в lvm тоесть еще несколько небольших разделов по несколько сотне мб.

Comment: тогда просто пересоздай таблицу разделов fdisk'ом и всего то... только внимательно на первый сектор: раздел мог начинаться с 63-го сектора (если изначально создавался в режиме совместимости с DOS), а мог с первого магабайта (2048-й сектор)

Comment: Как это сделать? 

Сканирование gparted ничего не дало. Просканировал с помощью testdisk, и нашло 5 разделов. Видимо некоторые из них те что создавались еще в прошлом, до нынешней утраченной разметки. читаются файлы только с одного, там где grub. Логично что с других не должно читаться т.к. это LVM

Comment: `fdisk`'ом пользовался? если да, то начни с чистой таблицы разделов (`o`) и просто создай один раздел на весь диск (`p`) и несколько раз enter и присвой ему тип lvm (`t`->`8e`), после чего сохрани (`w`). После чего `pvscan` должен будет найти том lvm'а... Если не поможет попробуй проделать всё тоже самое, только с включённым флагом dos-совместимости (`c`). Все эти действия работают только с таблицей разделов и при должном отношении не должны запортить данные, но будь осторожен... Если не понятно, то могу расписать подробней позже (сильно позже).

Comment: fdisk -l только юзал. А что если на аналогичном жестком диске такого же размера прожечь винт рандомными байтами, установить туда такую же систему в том же порядке как и устанавливал на винчестере, с которого по ошибке удалил разделы. Затем удалить разделы со свежеустановленной системы и попробовать его просканировать на удаленные разделы. В результате должны отобразится только необходимые разделы, аналогичные которым впоследствии можно выбрать для восстановления на нужном винчестере. Мой уровень знания линукса придумал только такую идею

Comment: https://ibb.co/d9rJhS - вот тут скриншот окна программы testdisk, который нашел некоторые нужные + ненужные разделы. Проблема только в том как их отличить. Если бы не было lvm-шифрования, было бы легче: восстановить данные через testdisk и/или разделы, которые читаются корректно и содержат необходимые файлы. А в случае с шифрованием, приходится наугад

Comment: гмм... я перестал понимать, что там было и что именно ты понимаешь под термином «lvm-шифрование»...